# Share interface/type among Lambda Functions with Lambda Layer

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a lambda layer file which has a definition of enum(which will be used in different lambda functions) like the following:

```
    exports enum EventTypes { 
      Create,
      Delete,
      Update,
    }
```

This works fine as I tested in different lambda functions.
Then I added more interface definitions in the same file and imported them in my implementation code. It finally looks like this:

```
    exports enum EventTypes { 
      Create,
      Delete,
      Update,
    }
    export interface ProjectEvent {
      eventType: EventTypes;
    }
    export interface CreateEvent extends ProjectEvent {
      userId: string;
    }
    export interface DeleteEvent extends ProjectEvent {
     userList: string[];
    }
    export interface UpdateEvent extends ProjectEvent {
     userList: string[];
    }
```

With this version of file, I couldn't even build the project successfully.
My question is: is there any restriction that I missed when integrating Typescript with Lambda layer?

Below is what I referred to setup my typescript-aws integration:

[1] https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2636

[2] https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/serverless-typescript-a-complete-setup-for-aws-sam-lambda

Comment: Lambda Layers are going to be extremely inefficient if you are just using them to share types - build an internal npm package and use that across the multiple functions if all you are sharing are types, services etc.

Comment: In addition to Ermiya (who is always excellent at AWS questions) you can't directly pass an object from one lambda to another - it always gets turned into a JSON between lambdas. So, if you have any lambdas acting in concert then you'll have more overhead and more bug prone areas as you have to map the json object into your interface. Its far better just to use json compatible objects to store and pass your data internally and between lambdas for this reason.  OOP and a lot of classic Class Inheritance goes out the window when stringing lambdas together (concentrate on the messages!)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thank you very much for your suggestion, this is absolutely the best practice to share interfaces definition across the functions!

Comment: @lynkfox thank you for the kind words :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason which is quite silly.

At the very first beginning, after finishing my implementation, I ran unit test locally and get the error:

```
Cannot find module 'opt/nodejs/interface';
```

In order to fix it, I did some modification in 'tsconfig.json' file to help my unit test find the lambda layer which breaks my build process. But in fact, all the configuration I had before was correct.

What really gets me into this issue is the way I importing something from layer.
This doesn't work:

```
// @ts-ignore can be ignored as this is a Lambda layer
import {
  A,
  B,
  C
} from '/opt/nodejs/interface'// Result: Cannot find module 'opt/nodejs/interface' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

This works

```
// @ts-ignore can be ignored as this is a Lambda layer
import { A, B } from '/opt/nodejs/interface'
// @ts-ignore can be ignored as this is a Lambda layer
import { C } from '/opt/nodejs/interface'
```

It's just the @ts-ignore only works for one single line below it.